# Invisible unicode characters loaded to DB in python

Tags: python, mysql, string, unicode, replace

There are many questions and fixes for this but none seems to work for me.
My problem is I am reading a file with strings and loading each line into DB.

In file it is looking like normal text,while in DB it is read as a unicode space. I tried replacing it with a space and similar options but none worked.

For example in text file the string will be like:

```
The abrupt departure
```

After inserted in DB, there it is looking like:

```
The abruptÂ departure
```

When I am trying to run query for data in DB, it is looking like:

```
"The abrupt\xc2\xa0departure"
```

I tried the following:

```
if "\xc2\xa0"  in str: 
     str.replace('\xa0', ' ')
     str.replace('\xc2', ' ')
     print str
```

the above code is printing the string like:

```
The abrupt departure
```

but while inserting back to DB, it is still the same.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `str.replace()` doesn't do anything to the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

This will remove `Unicode` character

```
>>> s = "The abruptÂ departure"
>>> s = s.decode('unicode_escape').encode('ascii','ignore')
>>> s
'The abrupt departure'
```

Or,
You can try with replace as you have tried. But you forget to reassign to same variable.

```
>>> s = "The abruptÂ departure"
>>> s = s.replace('\xc2', '').replace('\xa0','')
>>> s
'The abrupt departure'
```

Comment: This worked but I got it like 
The abruptdeparture without space in between.

Comment: Which python version you are using?

Comment: it is 2.7 does it matter?

Comment: the way it is read is not like "The abruptÂ departure" but like this
"The abrupt\xc2\xa0departure"

Answer (score 1):

The point is strings are immutable, you need to assign the return value from `replace`:

```
 s = s.replace('\xa0', ' ')
 s = s.replace('\xc2', ' ')
```

Also, don't use `str` as a variable name.

Answer (score 1):

`C2A0` is a "NO-BREAK SPACE".  `'Â '` is what you see if your `CHARATER SET` settings are inconsistent.

Doing a `replace()` is merely masking the problem, and not helping when a different funny character comes into your table.

Since you have not provided enough info to say what you have done correctly versus incorrectly, let me point you at two references:

- [Things to check for in Python](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#python)
- [The things you *should* do for utf8, and what may have gone wrong to get "Mojibake"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38363567/1766831)